# Performance of HtmlHelper vs Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a performance difference between using an HtmlHelper or a Partial for a given task?

For example, I'm writing an HtmlHelper "control" to create a link in an editor with the following signature:

```
public static HtmlString RecordNameLink(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        string editActionName, 
        object editRouteValues, 
        string deleteActionName = null, 
        object deleteRouteValues = null)
```

In this case the edit button will always be displayed, and the delete button will only be displayed if it is included. Alternately, I could do this:

```
@Html.Partial("Controls/RecordNameLink", Model)
```

(Or pass a partial-specific model)

But is there a *reason* to choose one over the other, specifically does one have better performance than the other? (though I'm open to learning more about the differences in general)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVC 3, for this sort of thing its going to be faster for you to render with an html helper than a Partial.

Do a test where you render a partial 100+ times in a loop, vs have the partial contain the loop (partial render per row of a table, vs partial render of all rows of a table). You might be quite surprised at the result.

Your HTML Helper will skip the viewengine having to hunt for the partial, the call to the Virtual Path Provider to load it, etc.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. There was another HtmlHelper that I changed out for a partial that is used almost everywhere, and the app is quite slow. I thought it was because of automapper deep-loading from the database during domain mapping, but this could be a culprit as well, so I'll see about switching it back. Thanks!

Comment: The only place you are going to see this is when you had a *ton* of a given partial rendering on a given page. It's not that partials are particularly slow, its just a question of volume.

Comment: Yeah, I just rechecked and I had previously refactored to use a partial that just called the HtmlHelper. Thought it would be "more proper" for some reason. In one screen the partial is called 1,169 times! (accounting report, 167 entries, each has 7 numbers, the partial/helper formats the numbers positive or negative and colors them green or red in certain columns). So yeah, I think I was taking a serious performance hit. :) Thanks again, I'm cleaning it all up now. Boy was I naive when I did that, wow.

Comment: You and the rest of us. Many of us have been hit by that before.